# file conversion- .mwb to .sql file

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have a database in .mwb format. I want to use it in eclipse so i need to convert it into .sql format. If anyone know how to do that by using any tool. I think My sql workbench can do that, but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the menu click "Database" and then "Forward engineering" (shortcut CTRL+G).

UPDATE:

Your .mwb file is a proprietary format, which also holds information of the graphical representation in Workbench. Your generated .sql file is a script, which your MySQL server needs to interpret. To create the database you designed via command line write something like this in the console of your choice:

```
mysql -u yourUser -p yourDatabase < yourFile.sql
```

You can omit "yourDatabase" when you create it with your script.

Comment: i tried that and then clicked next and next after that i saved the file but now i am not able to open that file. How can i open that file

Comment: @VikasGupta Edited my answer. Ask if you have more questions.

Comment: thanks for replying, but i am very week in using command line. So isn't there any other war?

Comment: @VikasGupta You can of course use a GUI like "Toad for MySQL", "HeidiSQL" or "Navicat" and open your .sql file in there and run it.

Comment: Also, phpMyAdmin. Good god, how did the OP survive this far?!

Comment: File -> Open Model (select .mwb file) then Database -> Forward Engineering

Answer (score 4):

Forward Engineering on my Debian installation of workbench did not work.
This worked for me to convert .mwb file to .sql file.

https://github.com/tomoemon/mwb2sql